# Segmentation Fault: C code snippet

Tags: c

I keep getting segmentation fault. What am I doing wrong?

The code is to take a limit, n and find the sum of even fibonacci terms from 1 to n.

code is on the image

[image: code image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `scanf("%d", n);` --> `scanf("%d", &n);`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score -1):

The variable `nextTerm` is not initialized. The loop condition uses it though. That might be a problem.